# Upload image in php and some error

Tags: php, file-upload

in my php page I have `<input type='file' name='aimage[]' id='aimage' />`
and a snippet code to get this file as :

```
    foreach($_FILES["aimage"]["tmp_name"] as $file)
    {
    /***  get the image info. ***/
     if(is_uploaded_file($file) && getimagesize($file) != false){

    $size = getimagesize($file);
    /*** assign our variables ***/
    $type = $size['mime'];
    $imgfp = fopen($file, 'rb');
    $size = $size[3];
   // $name = $file['name'];
    $maxsize = 99999999;


    /***  check the file is less than the maximum file size ***/
    //if($_FILES['aimage']['size'] < $maxsize )
      //  {
        /*** connect to db ***/
        $formvars['file'] = fread($imgfp, getimagesize($file));
```

Although using foreach, I got error as Warning: fread() expects parameter 2 to be long, array given in. what's cause of this error? How can I check only images uploaded to site and other files detected by code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is caused by the second parameter of fread() : `getimagesize($file))` which returns an array and not a long. [getimagesize](https://www.php.net/getimagesize) returns an array(width, height)

Maybe you want to use `filesize($file)` instead

Answer (score 0):

From the `getimagesize` documentation:

> Returns an array with up to 7 elements. Not all image types will
>   include the channels and bits elements.
>
> Index 0 and 1 contains respectively the width and the height of the
>   image.
>
> Note: Some formats may contain no image or may contain multiple
>   images. In these cases, getimagesize() might not be able to properly
>   determine the image size. getimagesize() will return zero for width
>   and height in these cases. Index 2 is one of the IMAGETYPE_XXX
>   constants indicating the type of the image.
>
> Index 3 is a text string with the correct height="yyy" width="xxx"
>   string that can be used directly in an IMG tag.
>
> mime is the correspondant MIME type of the image. This information can
>   be used to deliver images with the correct HTTP Content-type header:
>
> Example #1 getimagesize() and MIME types